# Install and run android for phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am using the documentation provided by phonegap

[PhoneGap Installation](http://phonegap.com/install/)
I am stuck at the third command

```
   phonegap run android
```

I am getting the following error.

[image: Make sure ant installed]

I have been trying to solve it for so many days.
Please someone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know this ugly install doc. It's better to follow the [cli docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) or/and  [platform guide docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to install all required dependencies.

And here in your case, if you read the message on the screen, it says you are missing the apache ant program or it's not added to your path.